# При деплое проекта SharePoint в C# получаю ошибку: File not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint

Добрый день.
Есть C#-проект солюшена для SharePoint. Мне нужно сделать сначала Build solution, затем Deploy solution.

Выделяю проект, правым кликом делаю "**Clean solution**" - всё ок.
затем: правый клик "**Build solution**" - всё ок.
затем: правый клик "**Deploy solution**" - получаю ошибку вида:

```
Error: File not found: F:\Projects\My.Timers\My.Timers\Package\Package.package.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Проблема в том, что файл "Package.package" реально существует по указанному пути.

Права даны полные на всю папку проекта с подфайлами. Антивирусов нет.
С путями вроде бы всё ок. Народ, что не так с моим проектом???

Comment: А что за точка в конце? `Package.package.`

Comment: Я не знаю. Точнее её нет нигде, ни в конфигурационных файлах ни в реальных именах. Возможно это так конец предложения студия заканчивает. Но да, вообще странно. Причем, если подпапку Package (внутри которой лежит файл Package.package) перенести в корень диска, а в My.Timers.csproj поправить путь до нового месторасположения, то уже такой ошибки не возникает, и .wsp файл создается корректно.

Answer (score 2):

Была подобная ошибка. В моем случае она решилась следующим образом:

1. В Visual Studio в исходном проекте открыть файл `Package.package`;
2. Перейти на вкладку `Advanced` и посмотреть есть ли там какие либо зависимости от сборок текущего проекта или внешних сборок.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем случае необходимо было удалить зависимости от удаленных сборок.